# there exists a countable infinite set M0⊆M, so that M and M∖M0 are equipotent.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The question as I understand it (it's in german) reads: Two sets X, Y are equipotent when a bijective mapping f: X → Y exists. Show that: a) M is an infinite set. Then there exists a countable infinite set M0⊆M, so that M and M∖M0 are equipotent. Note: Show initially that any infinite set has a countable infinite subset.

Comment: Are you sure $M$ is not **un**countable ?

Comment: The (question asked by the title) is false, but your actual question is different, and true. I'd edit the title, but this will make the two existing answers seem crazy. They answer your title, not the body of your question.

Comment: Can you add the question in German? Just in case something got lost in the translation or something.

Comment: Zwei Mengen X, Y heißen gleichm¨achtig, wenn eine bijektive Abbildung f : X → Y existiert. Zeigen
Sie:
a) Sei M eine unendliche Menge. Dann existiert eine abz¨ahlbar unendliche Menge M0 ⊆ M,
sodass M und M \ M0 gleichm¨achtig sind.
Hinweis: Zeigen Sie zun¨achst, dass jede unendliche Menge eine abz¨ahlbar unendliche Teilmenge
hat.
b) (−1, 1) und R sind gleichm¨achtig.

Comment: I didn't ask about b) in this thread but you can help with that as well if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't true in general.  For instance, if $M_0=M$, then $M\setminus M_0$ is empty, and thus certainly not equipotent to $M$!

Comment: The question as I understand it (it's in german) reads:                                               Two sets X, Y are equipotent when a bijective mapping f: X → Y exists. Show that:
a) M is an infinite set. Then there exists a countable infinite set $M_0 ⊆ M$, so that M and $M∖M0$ are equipotent.                                          Note: Show initially that any infinite set has a countable infinite subset.

Comment: @babylon: Right, so the problem only asks you to show that _there exists_ a countably infinite subset $M_0\subseteq M$ such that this is true.  It might not be true for _every_ countably infinite subset $M_0$; you'll have to pick a special one.

Comment: Ah ok I see - so how did the 'note' help me in answering this question? I thought it would help but it doesn't seem helpful..?

Comment: @babylon: Here's a hint.  As the note suggests, first find a countably infinite subset of $M$.  However, don't just take that countably infinite subset to be your $M_0$; call it $M_1$ instead.  To get $M_0$, choose a subset $M_0\subseteq M_1$ such that $M_0$ and $M_1\setminus M_0$ are both countably infinite.

Comment: Such as Z and 2Z..?

Comment: @babylon Sure, such as $\Bbb Z$ and  $2 \Bbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

As it is stated, it's false :

Take $M = \Bbb N$ and $M_0 = \{ n \in \Bbb N | n > 5 \}$

Both are countably infinite, but clearly $M\backslash M_0 = \{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ is not equipotent to $M= \Bbb N$